# Kitties tutorial part 1 build is failing with unresolved import for sc_client_api RemoteBackend, anyone faced this issue?

Tags: rust, substrate

I just followed the tutorial, I am at the first

```
cargo build --release
```

This is the error I am getting, any idea why this would happen?

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sc_client_api::RemoteBackend`
 --> node/src/service.rs:4:39
  |
4 | use sc_client_api::{ExecutorProvider, RemoteBackend};
  |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                       |
  |                                       no `RemoteBackend` in the root
  |                                       help: a similar name exists in the module: `StateBackend`
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing `RemoteBackend` from the import at `node/src/service.rs`.

Just change the line (for me it was Line 4) at `node/src/service.rs` from

```
use sc_client_api::{ExecutorProvider, RemoteBackend};
```

to

```
use sc_client_api::ExecutorProvider;
```

---

While working with the tutorial `cargo build --release` resulted in the following error message:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sc_client_api::RemoteBackend`
 --> node/src/service.rs:4:39
  |
4 | use sc_client_api::{ExecutorProvider, RemoteBackend};
  |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                       |
  |                                       no `RemoteBackend` in the root
  |                                       help: a similar name exists in the module: `StateBackend`
```

The `help` message provided some clue as to what was happening. Checking the `node/src/service.rs` file, I found that `RemoteBackend` was never referenced anywhere else in the file. So I simply removed it from the imports, and the build process was completed successfully.

Comment: I moved forward changing it to StateBackend as suggested by the compiler.. didnt want to totally remove it. 

There was another issue where it complained about unresolved pallet for this line in pallets/../src/lib.rs
pub use pallet::*;

Changed it to pub use frame_system::pallet::*; and that solved that issue

Now stuck with 
error: expected `OriginFor`
   --> pallets/../src/lib.rs:155:20
    |
155 |             owner: &T::AccountId,

in the mint function. 
Did you face this?

Comment: removed the helper mint function and put the code in create function and moved on with that...